# Sorting of partitioned data in snowflake copy into command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a copy into command which unloads data from snowflake to a stage in parquet files. We are partitioning the data by one columns as well. Is it possible to sort the partitioned data by some column value.??

sample query:

copy into @Stage/data from
(select deptid, ename, salary from employees order by ename) partition by (deptid) HEADER=true

Sorting by partition by column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible to run the query, however, based on the Snowflake documentation there is no guarantee that the order of the data loaded using PARTITION BY and ORDER BY will be kept for the unloaded files.

See the note below in the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#optional-parameters):
*Including the ORDER BY clause in the SQL statement in combination with PARTITION BY does not guarantee that the specified order is preserved in the unloaded files.*